# Why can't I get the $sceProvider?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I'm trying to create a filter using `$sceProvider` to unescape the HTML tags.

This is how my code looks like:

```
myApp.filter('unescapeHtml', function($sce) {
return function(item) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(item);
};
```

But when I use this filter in my code, this error occurs.
[image]

I have another snippet like this, but has the same error:

```
myApp.filter('unescapeHtml', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
return function(item) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(item);
};
```

}]);

I searched online about this seems no working solution for me.

I did have this work in another page of my application, the only difference is that the working one is being injected into a controller, like this:

```
function myController($scope, $http, $sce) {
```

Did I miss something? I totally have no idea what's going on here, any help will be grateful.

Comment: yes you need to inject

Comment: I edited my question. Is there something wrong with my injection?

Comment: your unescapeHtml filter is correct

Comment: try with a function in the filter `.filter('unsafe', function ($sce) {
   return function (val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
   };
});`

Comment: Which one is correct? I tried with your code, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try injecting dependency using below way.

```
app.filter('unescapeHtml', ['$sce', function($sce){
   return function (val) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(val);
   };
}]);
```

Comment: app.filter('unescapeHtml', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function(item) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(item);
    };
}]);
This is my another code for testing, but not working.